# How to change/rename specific attributes within a data frame column

Tags: r, attributes, dataframe

I need help changing/renaming attributes within columns of a data frame in R. I can get pretty close to what I need, but I haven't been able to work around the way that my "solution" changes the data.

Here's a dummy data frame:

```
cols <- c("green", "green", "red", "blue", "black", "blue")
num <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3)
df <- data.frame(cols, num)

df$cols <- as.character(df$cols)

> df
   cols num
1 green   1
2 green   1
3   red   2
4  blue   3
5 black   4
6  blue   3
```

Let's say there was a mistake in my data and that all of my "green" attributes need to be "purple." Here's the bit of code I tried that was suggested over at the GIS StackExchange for a similar problem:

```
df[df$cols == "green", ] <- "purple"

> df
    cols    num
1 purple purple
2 purple purple
3    red      2
4   blue      3
5  black      4
6   blue      3
```

As you can see, it does indeed change my green attributes to purple...but also changes its corresponding number column. With my real data frame, I have many other necessary columns that can't be changed like this. So how do I change attribute names within a column WITHOUT affecting other columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be either

```
 df$cols[df$cols=="green"] <- "purple"
```

Or

```
 df[df$cols=="green", "cols"] <- "purple"
```

In both the cases, we are specifying the column name. In the first case, the logical index (`df$cols=="green"` - a `vector`) we got can be used to subset the rows in the "cols" (`df$cols[df$cols=="green"]`) and then assign it to `"purple"`.  The second case may be more useful, when there are multiple columns.  If we have say, two columns, `"col1",`"col2"`, just concatenate it`c("col1", "col2")`  (or specify the column index)

```
 df[df$cols=="green", c("col1", "col2")] <- "purple"
```

NOTE: The above is a test case.

---

In the OP's code, the column is not specified, i.e. after the `,` it is blank.  By default, it selects all the columns in the dataset and replace the rows that we got from the logical index with `"purple"`

Comment: In my real data, when I try the first solution, it spits out the error `Error in tz.finca$region[tz.finca$region == "Battambang", ] = "test" : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix`. EDIT: I misread your answer and believe I've got it right now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I tried dat[dat$date== "2020-06-07_12h33.46.880", "participant"] <- 101 for my question here but it does't work. What am I doing wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376988/rename-value-for-multiple-rows-based-on-other-variable